# jQuery Pass td onclick value to other table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I tried finding solution to this problem but I couldnt find the right article

```
    <div class="panel ui-widget-content" id="invoiceList">
<h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; "><span>Invoices</span></h2>
    <table cellspacing='0' id='header' class="ui-widget">
        <tr>
            <th>Invoice Number</th>
             <th>Invoice Total</th>
        </tr>     
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"  >INV-Error_Test1</a></td>
            <td>22.000000 USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            td><a href="#"  >INV-Error_Test2</a></td>
           <td>22.000000 USD</td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</div>
<div class='panel ui-widget-content' id="invoiceErrors">
<h2>Select a Invoice from the left to view Error Details</h2>
  <div class='panel ui-widget-content' id="invoiceHeaders">
    <h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; "><span>Invoice Headers</span></h2>
        <table class="ui-widget">
           <tr>
                <th>Invoice Number</th>
                 <th>Matter Number</th>
                <th>Invoice Total</th>
                <th>Invoice Tax Total</th>
                <th>Invoice Net Total</th>
          </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><%= invoiceNumber%></td>
            <td>CC_MAT_1221</td>
            <td>22.000000 USD</td>
            <td>22.000000 USD</td>
            <td>22.000000 USD</td>
        </tr>

        <td class = 'error'>File Error : The file does not contain any record delimiters or is in an unsupported format</td>

       </table> 
    </div>
    <div class='panel ui-widget-content' id="invoiceLines">
    <h2 class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-top" style="cursor: pointer; "><span>Invoice Line Items</span></h2>
     <table class="ui-widget">
        <tr>
            <th>Line Item Number</th>
            <th>Line Item Date</th>
            <th>Unit Cost</th>
            <th>Number of Units</th>
            <th>Line Item Total</th>
            <th>Task Code</th>
            <th>Expense Code</th>
            <th>Timekeeper ID</th>
            <th>Line Item Description</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>20150304</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>E2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <td class='error'><%= invoiceNumber%> Line : 2 Invoice does not foot Reported = (22.0)Calculated (18.0)</td>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>20150306</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>T3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/5n62md3m/

I was able to get the invoice number from `invoiceList` div as below

```
 $("#invoiceList a").click(function (e) {
console.log('invoice --->'+$(this).text());
});
```

But am not sure how to send this to `invoiceNumber` in `invoiceErrors` div

Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Better yet, thanks to one of the comments, give the cell an ID, ex '#invoice-number-error' then target that directly with jQuery, no need for .find(), makes everything faster.

aka:

```
$("#invoiceList").find('a').click(function (e) {
    var invoiceNumber = $(this).text();
    $('#invoice-number-error').text(invoiceNumber);
});
```

**OLD ANSWER**

I would suggest giving the table cells classes, I updated your filddle to reflect the one change:

I added the class 'invoice-number' to that cell under #invoiceErrors. Then I updated your function to look like this:

```
$("#invoiceList").find('a').click(function (e) {
    var invoiceNumber = $(this).text();
    $('#invoiceErrors').find('.invoice-number').text(invoiceNumber);
});
```

Comment: If you're going to do that, why not just give the cell an id and avoid find altogether?

Comment: My page is actually a jsp so adding invoiceNumber as text wont solve the issue. I have a ArrayList of invoices and I use the invoice number(on which uses clicks) to find the invoice object from the ArrayList and display the invoice values.

Comment: this is the original JSP `<% invoice =  lipData.invoices.find{it.invoiceNumber=='INV-Error_Test2'} %>
                     <tr>
                        <td><%=invoice.invoiceNumber%></td>
                         <td><%=invoice.matterNumber%></td>
                        <td><%=invoice.invoiceTotal%></td>
                        <td><%=invoice.invoiceTotal%></td>
                        <td><%=invoice.invoiceTotal%></td>
                  </tr>`   where `INV-Error_Test2` is hard coded. I need to get this from user click

Answer (score 0):

Give your table an id like `mytable` then do:

`$("#mytable td").eq(0).html( $(this).text() );`

### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/5n62md3m/6/)